# Apache Camel: CXF with SOAP: IndexOutOfBoundsException: From HandleInInterceptor handleMessage (line67). How to fix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I am using Apache Camel Route, where I need to perform Soap API call, for SOAP api, i am using Cxf library, while using it I am getting error like below -

```
09:45:12.430 [default-workqueue-1] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices}chargepointservices#{urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices}getTransactionData has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderInInterceptor.handleMessage(HolderInInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:808)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1701)
```

My Route -

```
from("direct:testSoapStart")
                .log("TestSoapApiRoute Initiated.")
                .process(this.soapRequestProcessor)
                //.setHeader(OPERATION_NAME, constant("getCPNInstances"))
                //.setHeader(OPERATION_NAME, constant("getOrgsAndStationGroups"))
                .setHeader(OPERATION_NAME, constant("getTransactionData"))
                .setHeader(OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices"))
                .toD("URL?"
                        + "serviceClass=dictionary.com_chargepoint_webservices.Chargepointservices"
                        + "&wsdlURL=/wsdl/cp_api_5.1.wsdl")
                .log("body :: ${body}")
                .process(this.soapResponseProcessor)
                .log("TestSoapApiRoute Completed.")
                .end();
```

In My SoapRequestProcessor - I'am adding Header and the body -

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST, soapHeaders);
exchange.getIn().setBody(new Object[]{new GetTransDataSearchRequest()});
```

I don't know why it's failing in HolderInInterceptor, The OutHolders List is having size one always, and all elements are null. Which is causing the problem. I am not having any information about this outHolders object, please help in this -

Or Do i need to replace the HolderInInterceptor ? If so How can we replace it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also show the wsdl ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found this question without an answer, so I want to share my solution.

The reason for my error was, that the generated interface had void methods instead of proper return type. The input object fields and output object fields were all added as input parameters of the void method. And my route was setting only the reqeust parameters and not prepareing holders for response parameters.

From the error `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1` i am guessing you had a single field(index=0) in the request element so its trying to find the first output param holder (HolderInInterceptor.java line 67).

Generating void methods should be only when the operation does not have an output message in its definition.

So if the interface methods are correctly generated as void methods, you should modify the route to set all the output fileds with holders like `javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String>` before the `.to()` method.

In my case I had both input and output messages, but it still generated void methods. I don't know if its a bug on the CXF side or the wsdl isn't correctly defined on the web service side I downloaded it from, but the problem was caused by having an identical name for the element used in message and the name of the operation.

Here is a github project where i showcase my problem  [Java CXF wsdl2java generation](https://github.com/marian-hlavenka/java-cxf-wsdl2java-generation-example)